# Screen Time Password working on iPadOS not on MacOS - with share across devices enabled

Tags: macos, passwords, ipad

Like many people here I have enabled Screen Time on two devices - iPad Pro Running ios13 and Macbook Pro running Catalina. My password works on my iPad though not on my Mac. I've tried resetting the password on the iPad. This works fine, though doesn't change what is happening on the Mac. I enabled share across devices.

Does the password for screen time get shared across devices? I've heard people say it is stored in the cloud. If that is the case - what maybe the issue here?

Thanks

Comment: Precisely which OS versions - afaik, both have had screen time bug-fixes & updates very recently [past week]

Comment: Hello Tetsujin,
I have MacOS 10.15.12 and iPadOS 13.3
I've created a new account on my Macbook Pro and it now has the same password as my iPad. Though the original Mac account is still locked with the old password.